# ClearCase: Describe of vobroot fails in windows, gives "null meta type" in Linux

Tags: clearcase

Running this command gives an error in Windows:

```
H:\>cleartool describe -fmt "%[object_kind]p" "M:\\my_cc_view\\"
```

it gives:

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to access "M:\\my_cc_view\": Input/output error.
```

Running the same command on a vob works:

```
H:\>cleartool describe -fmt "%[object_kind]p" "M:\\my_cc_view\\vob1"
directory version
H:\>cleartool describe -fmt "%[object_kind]p" "M:\\my_cc_view\\vob2"
directory version
```

In Linux it gives:

```
; cleartool describe -fmt "%[object_kind]p" /view/my_cc_view/vobs/
; null meta type**
```

I've been unable to find if this is a bug in clearcase, the closest one I could find was [this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21419816&ratlid=cctocbody).

It seems that running a describe on the the vobroot element is is a special case we must handle separately, is there a way to check if the path is the root?

Comment: Thanks, both answers were very helpful. Since @cjp obviously registered just to answer this question, I gave the answer to him/her :)

Comment: except cjp's answer is wrong and doesn't answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views, vobs, label types, branch types (etc) are referenced directly as follows.  In the docs these are called "object-selector".

```
cleartool describe view:my_cc_view
cleartool describe vob:vob1
```

See [`cleartool describe` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm).

Also, try a dot at the end to get the root directory element of a given vob.

```
cleartool describe /view/my_cc_view/vobs/.
```

Comment: Note: `view:` isn't a valid object selector. A view has no object-selector. Only a tag or a root path.

Answer (score 1):

> cleartool: Error: Unable to access "M:\my_cc_view\": Input/output error.

Not sure why you get two '\' here: with one, it works on my Windows session, but it won't give you much:

```
ct descr -fmt "%[object_kind]p" "m:\my_cc_view"
**null meta type**
```

A view hasn't really an "object type". And it has no "object-selector" like "`view:`"

To see all characteristic of a view, type:

```
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro my_cc_view
```

(using the tag of the view).

Comment: Note: to check if a directory is the root of the view, simply go one directory level up: if the '`ct lsview -cview` answers the current directory isn't a view, then the directory you were in before was in fact the root directory of the current view.